# SimplePie library is required for Feeds SimplePie Parser

Tags: feeds, theming

The [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) is reporting a warning about needing a SimplePie parser and prompts the user download a compiled version of it, but it isn't clear how/where to do this.

Where can I find the compiled version of the required library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull a compiled version of the parse from http://simplepie.org/downloads/simplepie_1.3.1.compiled.php. Rename this file simplepie.compiled.php and copy it in the  directory sites/all/libraries/simplepie/; the module should stop reporting the error.